# Simple integration problem: $h\int_0^T (Q-at)dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm not a math student, but I need to use the following formula for my project.

I have an equation:

> $$h\int_0^T (Q-at)dt$$

Also, $Q=aT$ (not sure would this help).

I want to integrate this equation and have the following result:
$$\frac{hQT}{2}$$
I can do the following:
$$h\int_0^T (Q-at)dt$$
Interate $(Q-at)$ gives:
$$h(\frac{Q-at^2}{2})$$
Substitute T and 0 gives:
$$h(\frac{Q-aT^2}{2}-\frac{Q}{2})$$
how to carry on? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting problem. Where did it come from?

Comment: I am studying supply chain management, this is one of the supply chain models

Comment: There isn't a single $=$ sign in your post, so there is no equation. And do you really mean that you can't simplify the expression ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$h\int_0^T (Q-at)dt=h\left(\int_0^T Qdt-\int_0^T atdt\right)=h\left(Qt]_0^T-\frac{at^2}{2}]_0^T\right)=h\left(QT-\frac{aT^2}{2}\right)=hT\left(Q-\frac{aT}{2}\right)=hT\left(aT-\frac{aT}{2}\right)=\frac{haT^2}{2}=\frac{hQT}{2}$$

Comment: Also for the last three steps, $hT(aT-aT/2)$ should equal $haT^2-haT^2/2$ right? why just $haT^2/2$ ?

Comment: @bigdata They are, in fact, the same. $haT^2-haT^2/2=(2haT^2)/2-haT^2/2=haT^2/2$

Answer (score 3):

You rather have
$$
h\int_0^T (Q-at)dt=h \left[Qt-\frac{at^2}2\right]_0^T=h\left(QT-\frac{aT^2}2 \right)=h\left(aT^2-\frac{aT^2}2 \right)=h\frac{aT^2}2,
$$ then put $aT=Q$ to get the announced result.